# Align image to bottom of responsive container

Tags: css, responsive-design, containers, fluid-layout

I'm trying to align images to the bottom of the container. However, as the site is responsive, when I change the window size the image moves up/down the container as it seems to be fixed a to a certain point on the page.

Is there a way to fix the baseline of the image to the baseline of the container indefinitely? Essentially, the image is aligned to the bottom to begin with, but as the window contacts, the text forces to container to expand and I end up with white space below the image.

My CSS for the image div is as follows:

```
.floatbottom {

height: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
width: 500px;

}
```

CSS for parent container:

```
#box{ 

height: auto;
padding-top: 90px;
padding-bottom: 90px;
position: relative;

}
```

HTML for image in container:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="floatbottom">
        <img src="/images/bottom.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas would be massively appreciated!

Comment: can you show the complete code pls ?

Comment: Done - I'd normally link the site, but the client has demanded a private (password/username) dev environment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: in you're css you show #ID box, but in you're HTML is .CLASS, error comes to from here ? => replace #box by .box{...}

Comment: Apologies, '#box' is true to the site just now - it's on Wordpress and in the backend I have an option to give the container div a class, but it needs to be an ID. Will this have an effect on the outcome?

Comment: you have try this : .floatbottom img{...} like selector ? it's curious the CSS it's good :/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="content"></div>
     <div class="floatbottom"></div>
 </div>
```

and set the css for content, height as auto; and container height also auto

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When I tried to use this it threw the image way out of the container and it ended up floating randomly on the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` combination in that case. You not need to use absolute position which is problematic when you will be scale your window. If you need to dynamically change your container height you can do it by use @media-query.

Some fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxytw/